# Uploading Symbolication for Parse crash report doesn't work

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm following the instruction on parse.com for uploading Symbolication. I stuck on this step:

> parse new

When it asked me for the email and password. I input my account email address and password. But I always got the following error message:

> Unable to authenticate with error: json: cannot unmarshal object into
>   Go value of type string.

What could be the reason? Thanks